# How　to update from subquery using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

```sql
UPDATE table  set id  ='999'
where seq = (
select seq FROM table
WHERE id is Null
ORDER BY seq
LIMIT 1)
```

please teach me

Comment: Why should i teach you ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Query Builder

```php
$subquery = DB::table('table')
    ->select('seq')
    ->whereNull('id')
    ->orderBy('seq')
    ->take(1)
    ->toSql();

$query = DB::table('table')
    ->whereRaw("seq = ($subquery)")
    ->update(['id' => 999]);
```

Raw query:

```php
$sql = 'UPDATE table SET id = 999 WHERE seq = (SELECT seq FROM table WHERE id IS NULL ORDER BY seq LIMIT 1)';
DB::statement($sql);
```